# Adjective describing a person with a Ph.D

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there perhaps a better way to say something like "a physicist with a Ph.D?" Is there an adjective that could come before physicist: "a ________ physicist?"

I was thinking "doctoral physicist" or "Ph.D physicist," but those don't seem quite right.

Comment: What context would you say that in? Are you being literary? Or what?

Comment: *Ph.D.* is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: @Lambie The context is literary. "I watched as Sam, a doctoral physicist, entered the room..."

Comment: @tchrist: A PhD candidate writing a PhD thesis in a PhD program might disagree with you.

Comment: @KarlG Then he's unstudied in the English language. Those are all nouns. Period. They are not adjectives. They fail the predicate-adjective test: "PhD candidate = candidate is PhD" fails. They fail the comparative test: "This PhD program is more PhD than that other PhD program". Those are both ungrammatical **BECAUSE THOSE ARE NOT ADJECTIVES**. Not everything that premodifies the noun in a noun phrase is an adjective. This is just a noun used attributively.

Comment: I thought as much. ***A Ph.D-wielding or Ph.D-brandishing or Ph.D-flouting physicist***, for attitude. Ah the beauty of English adjectives: noun plus verb + ing.

Comment: Does the answer _have_ to be an adjective, or would you be willing to consider words that might fit into a noun phrase such as in the example? As tchrist points out, insistence on an adjective rules out at least one otherwise possible answer.

Comment: @Lambie I merely mentioned that I'd seen *doctoral* used in conjunction with *doctoral students*, nothing more.

Comment: @tchrist, ah right. Gotcha. For those who ain't got this yet, it's literary and needs to show some kind of attitude: a Ph.D-carrying physicist, for sarcasm. Compare to: card carrying member of the Communist Party, for instance.

Comment: @tchrist (and whoever else may care...) Within the academy it is generally acceptable form to refer to someone as ***doctorally prepared***, a relatively current expression which seems to avoid any ambiguities, and which admits a variety of doctoral degrees such as JD, EdD, etc as professionally terminal.

Comment: Wanted: PhD physicist with post-doc experience in table-top neutrino detection to head extravagantly funded new program in Abu Dhabi.  Made up, but perfectly plausible.

Comment: @Lambie don't you mean PhD-flaunting?

Comment: Is there more context to this? An entire phrase/sentence?

Comment: @ab2 Yes, flaunting, my head was unscrewed yesterday Thanks! As a literary matter, I'd avoid Ph.D physicist like the plague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Postdoctoral' is the usual way to title someone with a PhD.

> Postdoctoral Physicist - Radiotherapy Physics
>   University of Oxford

[Jobs](http://www.jobs.ac.uk/job/AJH344)

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postdoctoral&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostdoctoral%3B%2Cc0) shows a steep rise of the use of the word from 1960 to the present.

Answer (score 4):

Usage of "PhD physicist" is steadily increasing. [Check out this N-Gram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=PhD%20physicist&year_start=1950&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPhD%20physicist%3B%2Cc0) An N-Gram, as opposed to a regular Google search, more accurately reflects elite usage, since only Google Books are searched. Use regular Google when you want to find out how many native speakers actually write "my husband and I's favorite."

PS.: As I suspected, there's a grand total of zero N-Gram hits for "doctoral physicist," so I suggest you discard that option.

Comment: PhD is not an adjective, and the request was for an adjective. Just how PhD is that scientist anyway? See!

Comment: Fine, but it functions as an adjective. A Harvard professor, A NASA astronomer, a cordon bleu chef...

Comment: A  Ph.D student but not a Ph.D physicist, it ain't kosher. It's OK to use a noun adjectivally but it has to work, as it were.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't blink if someone said a Ph.D physicist; it is a common usage.  If someone said "a doctoral physicist" I would have to guess if the person in question was a doctoral candidate or a Ph.D physicist (and what country the speaker came from.)

Comment: No, it does not function as an adjective. Adjectives can be a popular predicate, and this cannot. Adjectives can be inflected into the comparative and superlative degrees, and this cannot. Adjectives can accept intensifiers and adverbs, and thus cannot. Adjectives cannot be modified by adjectives, but this can. It is a noun that cannot function as an adjective. Nouns can be used as premodifiers of nouns.

Comment: Other things that can premodify nouns that are not adjectives include articles, quantifiers, determiners, and predeterminers. Nouns aren't special in this property of being able to modify a noun without becoming an adjective. Happens all the time.

Comment: OK, let's call it a noun used as a modifier then.